# HTML : writing page title by all means

Tags: html, tags, title, page-title

I would like to know how to set the page title by all means.
I currently know two ways only :

```
<title>xxxxx</title>
```

And

```
<meta name="title" content="xxxxx" />
```

Is there more ?

The reason why i need to know that is because i have to create an application that reads the page title from a webpage so it must handle all cases.

Comment: Why is this needed? Just use <title></title>

Comment: It would be an extra information to know about how to set title by other means other than the usual title tag.

Comment: `<title></title>` is the universally supported and recommended way to do it. Why do you need another method?

Comment: This is an [open ended question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) and badly defined as well. Do you mean only on the client side?

Comment: Okay i`ll edit my question to add more information..

Comment: I also think that the title-tag is the only one you should take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript can change it. when load is completed, so actual title might not be the one written first time in html

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    document.title = "xxxxxxxx";
});
```

Comment: Haha, haven't seen the jQuery meme for a while!

Comment: That's not a title change by jQuery, but JavaScript. This is the jQuery way to do it: `$(document).attr('title', 'xxxx')` (and `prop` instead of `attr`).

Comment: But he didn't asked how to change the title. He asked, which tag he should read (whatever method he uses, jQuery on a page, a crawler for multiple pages). I'm also not sure whether it is a good practice regarding SEO to change the title of a document with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The only real way to set the title is using:

```
<title></title>
```

However, some sites might also have Opengraph, Dublin core or Schema tags.

As the title element is required as part of HTML, I would use that.